# ng-keyup is not working at rendering side

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code in HTML (Angular):

```
<input ng-value="minLoanRange" tabindex="1" lable-up id="minLoanRange" class="inputMaterial" ng-model="minLoanRange" ng-disabled="activeType" type="number" max-length-handler required value="" ng-keyup="addCommas(minLoanRange)"/>
```

Here is my code of `addCommas`:

```
$scope.addCommas = function(nStr){
    nStr+='';
    var x = nStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while(rgx.test(x1)){
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    $scope.minLoanRange = x1+x2;
}
```

I have put an alert just before `$scope.minLoanRange = x1+x2;` like `alert(x1+x2);` It is working properly, just not reflecting on screen.

Comment: It's urgent please answer as soon as possible in advance Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two different variables - one for the model value and one for the value. Here's a working snippet to demonstrate how you can accomplish what you're after.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.modelValue = 0;
    $scope.commaValue = '';
    $scope.addComma = function() {
      let nStr = '' + $scope.modelValue.replace(',', '');
      var x = nStr.split('.');
      var x1 = x[0];
      var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
      var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
      while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
      }
      $scope.commaValue = x1 + x2;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <input ng-value="commaValue" ng-model="modelValue" ng-keyup="addComma()">
</div>
```

Comment: @Arti What isn't working? Run the code snippet in the answer -  seems to be working. There's a bug in your comma adding routine when you get more than 7 digits, though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `value=""` and `ng-value`. Because ng-model supports two way binding. if  you assign correct value to that model object. its automatically reflect to html.

I have copied the snippet from @lex answer and made some changes

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.modelValue = 0;
    $scope.commaValue = '';
    $scope.addComma = function() {
      let nStr = '' + $scope.modelValue.replace(',', '');
      var x = nStr.split('.');
      var x1 = x[0];
      var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
      var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
      while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
      }
      $scope.modelValue = x1 + x2;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <input ng-model="modelValue" ng-keyup="addComma()">
</div>
```